# Sketch the image under $w=\log(z)$ of the set, $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}<|z|<e^{\frac{\pi}{4}},\Re(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Sketch the image under $w=\log(z)$ of the set, $$A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}<|z|<e^{\frac{\pi}{4}},\Re(z)>0\}$$

$\log(z)=\ln |z| +iArg(z)$ where $-\pi<Arg(z)\leq\pi$ is the principal argument of $z$.

$w=\log z$ or $e^{u+iv}=x+iy$ shows that
\begin{cases}
e^u\cos v=x>0 \quad(\Re(z)>0)\implies -\dfrac{\pi}{2}<v<\dfrac{\pi}{2},\\
e^u\sin v=y.
\end{cases}

But I have no idea how to use the condition $$e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}<|z|<e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\implies e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$ of the open half annulus. Is it give the bound of $u$? How?

Any solution/hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take logarithms in $e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}<|z|<e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$  and note that $\ln |z|$ is the real part of $log \, z$. The answer is $\{w: -\frac {\pi} 4 <\Re w <\frac {\pi} 4, -\frac {\pi} 2<\Im w <\frac {\pi} 2\}$

Comment: I understand how to get $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\Im{w}<\frac{\pi}{2}$ but didn't get the $\Re w$ @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: By definition  of principal logarithm the real part of $log z$ is $\ln |z|$. @falamiw

Comment: Oh, no. I just mess up the definition. My fault.

Comment: I was thinking if the condition $\Re(z)$ is swapped by $\Im(z)$ then how to handle that case? @Kavi Rama Murthy. Like $a<\Im(z)<b$ without given $c<|z|<d$ constraint, because then I can't conclude anything quickly for $u$ or $v$. And sorry I forgot to accept your answer.